# ¿Como puedo tomar el valor a input tipo hidden en ionic usando ngmodel?

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7, ionic4, ionic-framework

En el formulario de registro de mi aplicación, quiero pasar el valor de un input tipo hidden usando ngmodel, al momento de mostrar el valor en consola el valor que toma es el de ngmodel, pero quisiera que el valor que tiene el input lo tomara el ngmodel. agradecido por su ayuda.

le dejo parte del código

aqui el TS:

```
    export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  address: any[] = [];

  registerUser: Usuario = {
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    type_dni: '',
    dni: '',
    states_id: '',
    cities_id: '',
    municipalities_id: '',
    parishes_id: '',
    address: '',
    role: 'client',
    password: '',
  };

  async register(fRegister: NgForm) {

    if (fRegister.invalid) {this.alert.infoAlert('Verifique los campos requeridos'); }

    console.log(fRegister.valid);

    console.log(this.registerUser);

    const valid = await this.auth.register(this.registerUser);

    if ( valid ) {
      this.NavCtrl.navigateRoot(['/main/tabs/tab1'], { animated: true} );
    } else {
      this.alert.infoAlert('El correo ya esta registrado');
    }
  }

}
```

Aqui el HTML:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="register(fRegister)" #fRegister="ngForm">
<ion-grid fixed>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-input type="hidden" name="role" [(ngModel)]="registerUser.role"></ion-input>
    <ion-col size="6"> <!-- input del nombre (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Nombre</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="name" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6"> <!-- input del apellido (cliente o courier)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Apellido</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="lastname" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.lastname"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6"> <!-- input del Email (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6"> <!-- input del Telefono (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Telefono</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="phone" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.phone"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="4"> <!-- input del tipo de documento (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Tipo</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="registerUser.type_dni" name="type_dni" required okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar">
          <ion-select-option name="type_dni" value="J">J</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option name="type_dni" value="V">V</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option name="type_dni" value="E">E</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="8"> <!-- input del numero de documento (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">N° documento</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="dni" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.dni"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let address of address.estado"> <!-- input del Estado para la direccion (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Estado</ion-label>
        <ion-select name="states_id" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.states_id" okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar">
          <ion-select-option value="{{address.id}}">{{address.name}}</ion-select-option>

        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let address of address.ciudad"> <!-- input de la Ciduad para la direccion (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Ciudad</ion-label>
        <ion-select name="cities_id" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.cities_id" okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar">
          <ion-select-option value="{{address.id}}" >{{address.name}}</ion-select-option>

        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6" > <!-- input del Municipio para la direccion (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Municipio</ion-label>
        <ion-select name="municipalities_id" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.municipalities_id" okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let address of address.municipio" value="{{address.id}}">{{address.name}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6"> <!-- input de la parroquia para la direccion (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Parroquia</ion-label>
        <ion-select  name="parishes_id" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.parishes_id" okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let address of address.parroquia" value="{{address.id}}">{{address.name}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="12"> <!-- input de la direccion del domicilio para la direccion (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Direccion de domicilio</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="address" required [(ngModel)]="registerUser.address"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="12"> <!-- input del tipo de documento (cliente, courier o proveedor)-->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Contraseña</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="registerUser.password" name="password" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="6">
      <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" color="success" type="submit">
        Registrarme
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
```

Comment: No entiendo, el input hidden está enlazado con la propiedad `role` `[(ngModel)]="registerUser.role`. Así que ambos van a tener el mismo valor. En qué momento cambia el valor del `input hidden`?. Explica un poco más tu pregunta.

Comment: exacto, que estoy haciendo mal para que en mi formulario envie el valor del input hidden. dejo de enlazarlo con el ngModel?, como puedo hacer esto estoy confundido , ya que en otros blogs dicen que el input hidden angular no lo lee.

Comment: Entonces a tu input hidden le asignas el valor con el ngModel y luego quieres que ese valor se envíe con el formulario?

Comment: disculpe lo tarde de la respuesta a su comentario, mas bien todo lo contrario quiero asignar el valor del input hidden al ngModel, pero no logro hacer esto, como puedo lograrlo?